# Como puedo renombrar un archivo antes de subirlo al servidor

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un formulario que procesa ciertos datos, estoy usando el siguiente código, y necesito saber como renombrar una imagen seleccionada, antes de subirla al servidor.

Es decir si cuando se selecciona la imagen esta se llama **imagen.png**, cambiarle el nombre por `$placa` en el php

Código PHP Usado

```
$placa = $_POST['placa'];
//UPLOAD FILE
$target_dir = "../../images/profiles/vh/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . $newfilename)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu casi lo tiene listo, lo primero que debes saber es cual es el tipo de la imagen que esta subiendo (`.jpg`, `.png`, etc). Ya que el valor recibido por `$_POST['placa']` solo tendrás el nombre me imagino y el tipo de archivo, por lo que tu debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$placa       = $_POST['placa'];
$newfilename = $placa . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"]; //concatena el nombre que le pasaste y agregale el tipo de imagen.
```

Luego mas abajo ya lo tienes:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . $newfilename)) { ... }
```

Espero y te funcione

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente concaténale el nombre aquí:

```
$placa = $_POST['placa'];
//UPLOAD FILE
$target_dir = "../../images/profiles/vh/";

$target_file = $target_dir . $placa;
$uploadOk = 1;
```